# ffmpeg metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, libavformat

I am encoding MPEG4/H264 to an mp4 file using libavformat (i.e. C libraries) I would like to add some metadata to the MP4 file such as date/time. Can someone give me some indication of how this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the metadata tag?
-metadata title="My Title" blahoutput.mp4

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

looking it over you can also use the -timestamp option